# visual studio 2010 not opening projects

Tags: visual-c++

i just installed visual studio 2010 and it is not opening any projects .I can make projects but i can not add any file in it and also it is not opening recent projects.
I am stuck here , kindly cooperate with me!

Answer (score 0):

OK, sounds like the installaion got munged up.

first obvious questions: do you have any code that has actually been saved?

If "yes," copy that code to an alternate location, and use the simplest solution:  use the Windows Control Panel to deinstall the MSVC instance and reinstall.  If no code saved, just de-install and reinstall.

That's the *obvious* answer.  You may also check the  location for the project files, and the settings Visual Studios uses.

1. from the toolbar, click "tools".
2. From the drop-down list select "options"
3. Within the displayed list, scroll down to "projects and solutions"

   - expand that list (click on the little "+" box)
   - 3 locations will be displayed.
   - Make sure you have write permission to all three locations
   - all the check boxes should be selected.  Especially the one marked "save new projects when created"
4. click "OK" to accept the changes